# Understanding a security proof of RingCT 3.0

Tags: ringct, security, cryptography

I am reading the paper "RingCT 3.0 for Blockchain Confidential Transaction:
Shorter Size and Stronger Security" (https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/508.pdf), an improvement to Ring Confidential Transactions.

However, I am having trouble understanding the first security proof (page 17, the definition is in page 8). Can someone help me out, please?

In particular I'm looking for some intution on the proof (with a reduced amount of mathematical notation).

Comment: It's not clear which proof you want help understanding. The first proof referenced p17 is "Lattice-based zero-knowledge proofs" is not discussed on p8.

Comment: That's a reference. The proof begins at the bottom of the page, where it says "Security Proofs".

Comment: You mean the proof on p17, A. Security Proofs, Theorem 4? What's throwing me is your statement "the definition is in page 8".